# Cannot find the declaration of element error for simple schema validation via code

Tags: java, xml, xsd, sax, saxparser

I have a problem with XML validation with a schema with the usage of javax.xml.validation.Schema.

I have a schema separated into two files.
The first one:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://sample/AAA/1.0.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="BBB">
        <xs:attribute name="firstName" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="lastName" use="optional">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

and the second one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://sample/AAA/1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://sample/AAA/1.0.xsd" version="0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:include schemaLocation="BBB1.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="AAA">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">Root element.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="BBB" type="BBB"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then I have a sample XML file I want to validate:

```
<AAA xmlns="http://sample/AAA/1.0.xsd">
  <BBB firstName="string" lastName="string"/>
</AAA>
```

I create a Schema instance as shown below:

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI, SAX_PARSER_FACTORY, null);
factory.setResourceResolver(new SchemeXsdResolver());
Schema schema = factory.newSchema(xsdStreamSource);
```

The xsdStreamSource is an array that contains two StreamSources (one per each XSD file).
Then I try to validate sample XML with a code:

```
SAXParserFactory parserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAX_PARSER_FACTORY_CLASS, null);
parserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
parserFactory.setSchema(schema);

SAXParser saxParser = parserFactory.newSAXParser();
SchemaValidatorErrorHandler errorHandler = new SchemaValidatorErrorHandler();
errorHandler.setLines(new String(content, "UTF-8").split("\\n"));
saxParser.parse(new BOMInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content)), errorHandler);
```

However, the errorHandler reports the error:

> /AAA[1] [cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'AAA'.].

Comment: I checked the XML/XSD with the `java hu.unideb.inf.validator.SchemaValidator` and the XSDs are working as expected. Cannot help you with the Java code, though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load schema with same namespace from more than one file, we have to enable additional feature when the schema is being created.

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI, SAX_PARSER_FACTORY, null);
factory.setFeature(Constants.XERCES_FEATURE_PREFIX + Constants.NAMESPACE_GROWTH_FEATURE, true);
factory.setResourceResolver(new SchemeXsdResolver());
return factory.newSchema(schemas);
```

Otherwise, only the first file with this namespace will be loaded and the second one will be skipped.